# RandomAccessFile to read xml file

Tags: java

I am trying to use RandomAccessFile to read xml file.  The thing is that I want to read only certain length at a time until end of file.

```
ReadUTF() read entire lines in the file which I do not want
Read(byte,start,end) seems what I need, but it is readying in byte so it doesnt contain the actual text of the read content.
```

Is there a way I can read a xml file in certain Length at a time using RandomAccessFile?

Thanks.

Comment: why do you want to do this?  xml isn't exactly a random access format.

Answer (score 0):

readUTF reads a single UTF encoded string which start with an unsigned 16-bit length followed by the string. As such it can contain many lines, but can't be used to read a text file.

RandomAccessFile is designed for binary formats, so there is little support for reading text.

Have you tried using BufferedReader and skip() to get random access?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the method `getChannel()` of `RandomAccessFile` to access to a part of a file.

For example here I map 2000 bytes starting at position 100 of a very large xml file (2go).

```
    FileChannel channel = new RandomAccessFile("frwiktionary-20120216-pages-meta-current.xml", "r").getChannel();
    ByteBuffer buffer = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 100, 2000);

    //Change the value with the proper encoding
    Charset chars = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"); 

    CharBuffer cbuf = chars.decode(buffer);
    System.out.println("buffer = " + cbuf);
```

Edit (see comment below)

It not only works with single-byte encoding, see this test :

```
FileOutputStream fop = new FileOutputStream("/home/alain/Bureau/utf16.txt");
try (OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(fop, "UTF-16")) {
    wr.write("test test toto 测");
}

FileChannel channel = new RandomAccessFile("/home/alain/Bureau/utf16.txt", "r").getChannel();
ByteBuffer buffer = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, channel.size());
Charset chars = Charset.forName("UTF-16");
CharBuffer cbuf = chars.decode(buffer);
System.out.println("buffer = " + cbuf);
```

> Output :
>
> buffer = test test toto 测

Comment: this only works if 1. the character encoding you use matches that of the xml file and 2. it is a single byte encoding.  risky at best...

Comment: @jtahlborn The user have to know the encoding of his file yes. But it doesn't only works with single-byte encoding. Take a look at the edit.

Comment: your edit works for the utf-16 encoding only because you have chosen your start boundary correctly.  if, however, you started on an odd byte, it would be broken.  and if you were working with utf-8, it would be impossible to choose a "correct" starting byte.

Comment: @jtahlborn Of course if you use utf-16 then you have to use multiple of 2 only. For me it's not such a hard requirement, if you think so it's your right.

Comment: @jtahlborn `if you were working with utf-8, it would be impossible to choose a "correct" starting byte` What are you talking about, it's the simpler case, replace UTF-16 by UTF-8 in the example. If you start at 5 it display `test toto 测`. Nothing simpler...

Comment: i suggest that you read up on utf-8 encoding before replying to my comment.

Comment: @jtahlborn What's the point, just tell me what's wrong? And just to clarify when I said `replace UTF-16 by UTF-8 ` it applies for the file writing and the file reading. If you use the proper encoding I don't see the problem. Give me an example that fail please.

Comment: utf8 is a variable width encoding where any given character can be _1 or more bytes_.

Comment: @jtahlborn I see your point. When I use this kind of method I start from 0, and move the position to the number of bytes previouly read. Clearly if you want to start at a random position relative to the number of actual characters you want to read/skip it can fail with utf-8 your right. By the way this case is not a requirement of the OP.